# jQuery: serialize() form and other parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, serialization

Is it possible to send *form* elements (serialized with [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method) and other parameters with a single AJAX request?

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'url',
    data : {
        $('#form').serialize(),
        par1 : 1,
        par2 : '2',
        par3: 232
    }
}
```

If not what's the best way to submit a form together with other parameters?

Thanks

Answer (score 276, accepted):

`serialize()` effectively turns the form values into a valid querystring, as such you can simply append to the string:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'url',
    data : $('#form').serialize() + "&par1=1&par2=2&par3=232"
})
```

Comment: @Falcon What do you mean of *coconut* in here?

Comment: how can i change 1 to variable

Comment: @Shafizadeh Its a rhyme  ( alot - coconut)

Comment: Can you please tell why here no need contentType?? Is that added by default?

Comment: Yes, form url encoded is the default. See the jquery documentation for more info

Comment: What about if we need to change the order of data sending in ajax call

Comment: @chamzz.dot late reply, but the order of arguments in a request is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 90):

Alternatively you could use `form.serialize()` with `$.param(object)` if you store your params in some object variable.  The usage would be:

```
var data = form.serialize() + '&' + $.param(object)
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param for further reference.

Comment: I like this one. It means I don't have to look at an ugly querystring!

Comment: This is the better way, by far. The accepted answer is messy and should never be used in any production application.

Comment: If we're talking about a production environment, then none of these answers should be used. The `form` should contain all information (in hidden fields if necessary) so that it can be serialised in a single call. This way if JS is disabled or fails, the form submission should still have a failsafe and include all data when sent.

Answer (score 11):

I dont know but none of the above worked for me, Then i used this and it worked :

In form's serialized array it is stored as key value pair

We pushed the new value or values here in form variable and then we can pass this variable directly now.

```
var form = $('form.sigPad').serializeArray();
var uniquekey = {
      name: "uniquekey",
      value: $('#UniqueKey').val()
};
form.push(uniquekey);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to send data with form serialize you may try this

```
var form= $("#formId");
$.ajax({
    type: form.attr('method'),
    url: form.attr('action'),
    data: form.serialize()+"&variable="+otherData,
    success: function (data) {
    var result=data;
    $('#result').attr("value",result);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#add_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var total_qty = $('#total_qty').text();
    var total_amt = $('#total_amt').text();
       
    $("#add_btn").val('adding....');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'action.php',
        method: 'post',
        data: $(this).serialize() + "&total_qty="+total_qty + "&total_amt="+total_amt,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }   
    });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

pass value of parameter like this

```
data : $('#form_id').serialize() + "&parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2"
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Following **Rory McCrossan** answer, if you want to send an **array** of integer (almost for .NET), this is the code:

```
// ...

url: "MyUrl",       //  For example --> @Url.Action("Method", "Controller")
method: "post",
traditional: true,  
data: 
    $('#myForm').serialize() +
    "&param1="xxx" +
    "&param2="33" +
    "&" + $.param({ paramArray: ["1","2","3"]}, true)
,             

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**encode in js :**

```
  var temp =    $("#pay_property_amount").serialize();
            temp = btoa(temp);
```

and pass in ajex

```
 data: { temp_data : temp },
```

**decode in php**

```
    $temp_data = base64_decode($this->input->post('temp_data'));

 if($temp_data){
$temp_data = $this->unserializeForm($temp_data);
 }


function unserializeForm($str) {
$returndata = array();
$strArray = explode("&", $str);
$i = 0;
foreach ($strArray as $item) {
    $array = explode("=", $item);
    
    if (preg_match('/(%5B%5D)/', $array[0])) {
          $array[0] = str_replace('%5B%5D','',$array[0]);
          if(array_key_exists($array[0],$returndata)){
                  $returndata[$array[0]][]=$array[1];
          }else{
              $returndata[$array[0]] =array();
              $returndata[$array[0]][]=$array[1];
          }
    }else
    {
        $returndata[$array[0]] = $array[1];
    }
    
    
}

return $returndata;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those who want to add new data to form data can use this method.
Exemple:

```js
$("form#myForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let formData = jQuery("#myForm").serializeArray();
    let newData = [
        {name:"city", value: "Ankara"},
        {name:"jobs", value: "Full-Stack Web Developer"},
        {name:"action", value: "ajax_proccess"} 
    ];
    let postData = formData.concat(newData);

    console.log(formData);
    console.log(newData);
    console.log(postData);

    jQuery(".alert").text("İş: " + postData[4]['value']);
    
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: jQuery("#myForm").attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: postData,
        success: function(data) {
            //let response = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(data);
            alert('Submitted.');
            jQuery(".alert").text(newData[5]);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="" id="myForm">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="Mahmut Yüksel">
<input type="hidden" name="surname" value="Mert">
<input type="hidden" name="countary" value="Turkey">
<input type="submit" value="Gönder">
</form>
<div class="alert">İş: </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cod 100% funcional 
<form id="formElem">
  <input type="text" name="firstName" value="John">
  Imagen: <input type="file" name="picture" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
  formElem.onsubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let response = await fetch('/article/formdata/post/user-avatar', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: new FormData(formElem)
    });

    let result = await response.json();
    enter code here
    alert(result.message);
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I fix the problem with under statement ;
send data with url same GET methode

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'includes/get_ajax_function.php?value=jack&id='+id,
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#b-info1').serializeArray(),
```

and get value with `$_REQUEST['value']` OR `$_GET['id']`

Answer (score -1):

You can also use serializeArray function to do the same.

Answer (score -2):

You can create an auxiliar form using jQuery with the content of another form and then add thath form other params so you only have to serialize it in the ajax call.

```
function createInput(name,value){
    return $('<input>').attr({
        name: name,
        value: value
    });
}
$form = $("<form></form>");
$form.append($("#your_form input").clone());
$form.append(createInput('input_name', 'input_value'));
$form.append(createInput('input_name_2', 'input_value_2'));
....

$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'url',
    data : $form.serialize()
}
```