# how to submit form using jquery in spring and retrive data in form in controller method

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I want to submit the form using jquery and at the same time whole form data should be send to controller and how to retrive that formdata in controller

suppose this is form

```
 <form action="#" id="userForm">
<span>userName :</span> <input type="text" id="userName"/>
<span>password :</span> <input type="password" id="password"/>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

this is jquery code

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
        $.post("login.html", {

        }, function(data) {

        });
        return false;
    });
```

and this is controller method

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/login.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody
        String login(HttpServletRequest request)
                throws Exception {
    return "success";
    }
```

Comment: I agree with @Baadshah a google search may also provide you how and what to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery serialize() method to send entire form data to controller and read by request.getparameter()
check this question [jquery-form-serialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398783/jquery-form-serialize-and-other-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you had forgot to add the link to your controller in the the url $post(). So , if you need to execute the logic inside your login method you must specify the exacte url , look at the possible correction

```html
$("#submit").click(function() {
        $.post("/nameOfController/login.html", {  
 
        }, function(data) {

        });
        return false;
    });
```