# Is it posible with ajax to send one json-array (array with json objects) and also include a separate parameter to receive in MVC action method?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

Is it posible with ajax to send one json-array (array with json objects) and also include a separate parameter to receive in MVC action method?

JavaScript:

```
var n = {
    number: 1           
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "html",
    data: JSON.stringify({jsonObjects:json, number:n}),
    success: function (response) {
        $('#body').html(response)
    }

});
```

MVC action:

```
public ActionResult Create(List<JsonObjects> jsonObjects, int? number)
```

JsonObjects is coming in like it supposed to but number is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your **n** variable declaration is wrong.

Try the following

```
var n = 1;

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html",
        data: JSON.stringify({jsonObjects:json, number:n}),
        success: function (response) {
            $('#body').html(response)
        }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
var n = 1;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "html",
    data: json+ "&number=" + n,
    success: function (response) {
        $('#body').html(response)
    }

});
```

I apologise if this doesn't work as I am unable to test this situation exactly, but the following line should be roughly what you are after and has worked for me in similar situations:

`data: json+ "&number=" + n,`

Also, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10398783/1129593) which may help you fix your problem.