# Don't show the #loading if the <input> is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Demo - jsfiddle.net/75CqW/

When someone clicks the Submit button, it shows the loading div even if the input is empty.

I don't want the user to see the #loading if he didn't write anything in the input, I've tried to add "required" in the input but the #loading is still showing when the input is empty. What do you think is wrong with my loading div?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of click handler use submit handler for the form - the form validation are triggered on form submit not on submit button click

```
$(function () {
    $("#myform").submit(function () {
        $("#controller").hide();
        $("#loading").show();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3UQs4/)

Note: You might want to prevent the default action of submit event so that the default form submit is prevented - if you are using ajax to do server side processing

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var id = $("#statusid").val();
if (id.length == 0)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, this script doesn't show the loading div, it starts the action of the form right away. Thank you :)

Comment: If you are wanting to have the loading image wait until a response from the server comes try using ajax and then hide the image on success.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test for a value (or run a validation check) on the field(s) before firing off the processing code

```
$(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function() {
        if $('#statusid').val() {
            $("#controller").hide();
            $( "#loading" ).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, this script doesn't show the loading div, it starts the action of the form right away just like user2310289's

Comment: The loading DIV wont show unless you change this to an ajax query since your page will always get replaced, loading div and all with a typical form submission. There are easy ways to serialize a form using jquery. jquery docs http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398783/jquery-form-serialize-and-other-parameters