# Serialize data attribute along with inputs name and value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, serialization

Is it possible to pass inputs `data` attibutes values when using jQuery's `serialize()` or `serializeArray()`?

**I don't want to append** the `data` values to already serialized form (like explained here: [jquery form.serialize and other parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398783/jquery-form-serialize-and-other-parameters)). I need to serialize `data` with field name and value at the same time, so I can get object like this:

```
{
    {name: 'field_1', value: 'ABC', id='1'}
    {name: 'field_2', value: 'XYZ', id='2'}
}
```

Example form:

```
<form name="" method="" action="">
    <input type="text"name="field_1" value="ABC" data-id="1">
    <input type="text" name="field_2" value="XYZ" data-id="2">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Is it doable or do I need to create such object manually?

Comment: Why not use a JSON string as the value? So: {val: 'ABC',id:1} JSON.Stringify that, and there you go.

Comment: Good one. Will surely try this out.

Comment: Great! good luck there :)