# data from js serialized what format in php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

```
var data = $('#demoform').serialize();
var action = $('#demoform').attr('data-action');
console.log(data)
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '../include/demo.php',
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    data: data,
    action: action
  },
  success: function(data) {

  }
}).done(function(data) {

});
```

In my php I get the data and I check it if the data is array like

```
$data =  $_POST['data'];
if (is_array($data)) {

}else{

}
```

I cant send it and when I use `print_r();` I can get

`task_date=11%2F30%2F2017+8%3A14+PM&task=qwe&task_person=qwe&task_status=0`

But I always end up in the else part meaning the data is not an array.

What is the format of the data if not array?

Comment: what is `$data`??

Comment: *I get the data* - how do you get it?

Comment: @Akintunde that is what I want to know. What is the format of data send from js using `.serialize();` if it is not an array what is it?

Comment: @splash58 I am sending it to php using ajax as shown above in the snippet

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: shouldn't it be `$_POST` you should be checking and not `$data`?? `$data` does not seem to be defined

Comment: @Akintunde i think he means `$data = $_POST["data"];`

Comment: @Akintunde updated

Comment: `$data` is obviously not an array here. check for example `!empty($data['task']);`

Comment: so i have to check one by one but why did it return should i get error for using `print_r()` for a string? @Akintunde

Comment: I don't understand why you receivw a string. But to proccees it `parse_str  ($data, $res);
print_r($res);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery form.serialize and other parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398783/jquery-form-serialize-and-other-parameters)

Comment: Perfect solution for your scenario in PHP - using `parse_str()`, I've just answered your question below, check if that is what you need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, `$_POST["data"]` is a url-encoded query string, see the [jQuery manual](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

> Description: Encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.

You need `parse_str()` to parse the query string <strike>first and then you can use `urldecode()` on the individual values to get the original values back</strike>.

**Edit:** As noted by @splash58, the values are already decoded, see the manual on [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

> **Note:**
>
> All variables created (or values returned into array if second parameter is set) are already urldecode()d.

So:

```
// Get the array
parse_str($_POST["data"], $data);
```

Comment: let me make it clear in the ajax i need to use `parse_str(data)` then in php i need to `urldecode($data)` ? then I use foreach now on them? I can check for array?

Comment: @Lloyd No, you need only `parse_str()` in php. Note that the results are set in the second parameter.

Comment: @jeroen the problem is on js side with making data

Comment: @splash58 It is unnecessarily complicated if you don't need to add extra fields, but I don't see a problem, you can send any string as the value.

Comment: @jeroen Of course, your solution solve the problem. But OP will not get error source while using this code. From this point of view, it's better to change js and use internal PHP method to create correct $_POST

Answer (score 0):

The data that you provided is not an array. It is a key-value pair, that can be accessed like $data['task']='qwe'

Comment: Its not a Key Value Pair, as print_r returns one big string not an array

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `urldecode()` on your data that you receive.

This might be what you are interested in -

```
<?php
    $data = "task_date=11%2F30%2F2017+8%3A14+PM&task=qwe&task_person=qwe&task_status=0";
    parse_str($data, $output);
    print_r($output);
?>
```

Which Results in - 
**`Array ( [task_date] => 11/30/2017 8:14 PM [task] => qwe [task_person] => qwe [task_status] => 0 )`**

Comment: This will not work if any of the values contain an encoded `&`.

Answer (score 0):

As I see you have some problem variable of ajax request. Please update your code as below.

```
var data = $('#demoform').serialize();
var action = $('#demoform').attr('data-action');
console.log(data)
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: action,
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {

  }
}).done(function(data) {

});
```

I hope this helps.