# serialize form data and add them to jquery $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#btnsave').click(function() {
    var id = $('.nameact').attr('data-id');
    var img = $('#imguser').attr('src');
    var uname = $('#inpuname').val();
    var pass = $('#inpass').val();
    var canpublic = $('#selcanpublic').val();
    var about = $('#txtabout').val();
    $.post('btn-save.php', {id, img, uname, pass, canpublic, about}, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

It works fine but because `inpuname, inpass, selcanpublic, txtabout` are all elements of a form (`forma`) I wonder is it possible to serialize that data and add them to `$.post` data?

Something like this:

```
$('#btnsave').click(function() {
    var id = $('.nameact').attr('data-id');
    var img = $('#imguser').attr('src');
    $.post('btn-save.php', {id, img, $('#forma').serialize()}, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Your second example is not valid at all. `serialize()` produces a querystring. While it's possible to append that to the object you send through jQuery it will require a lot of amendment to your serverside code which is not really what you're trying to do. I would guess you require something more like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398783/jquery-form-serialize-and-other-parameters/10398820#10398820) which appends other parameters to the serialised string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('form').serialize()` generates a querystring with values. So when you serialize your form it will send the values as url parameters.

It would generate as

```
http://example.com?id=value&img=value&uname=value&pass=value&canpublic=value&about=value
```

So there is one way you can send

```
var formData = $('#forma').serialize()+'&id='+idvalue +'&img='+imgValue;

 $.post('btn-save.php', formData, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

or you can [serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) to form. It will create `key-value` pair of form elements.

```
var formData = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
formData.push({name: 'id', value: idValue});
formData.push({name: 'img', value: imgValue});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FormData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) object. It stores form values.

**EDIT** you can use [`FormData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) only with option `processData: false,`

```
$('#btnsave').click(function () {
    var formData = new FormData($('#forma'));
    $.ajax({
        url: 'btn-save.php',
        data: formData,
        type: "POST",
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The FormData object is not supported in IE9 or lower. I assume if it is not a concern for OP.

Comment: Something is wrong - I'm getting `Unexpected token` error

Comment: tried - `$.post('btn-save.php', {id, img, formData}, function(data) {...` - getting - `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` - on this line

Comment: @puerto, yep, my bad. Edited answer.

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski, in that case there is no `code lines reducing` effect - what a pity

Comment: You can do it in one line if you want to. But if it did not help you, then sorry :)