# Post data $(form).serialize() and an array together

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble sending the form via ajax. In addition to the fields populated by the user, I need to send an `array` of objects together.

**AJAX POST:**

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: urlPost,
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: $(form).serialize() + JSON.stringify(myArray),
                        success: function (resposta) {
                           alert('success');
                        }
                    });
                }
```

If I send only `$(form).serialize()` I can, but with the `array` not.

**ARRAY:**

```
myArray = [{name: 'a', node: 1}, {name: 'b', node: 12}, ...];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `data: $(form).serialize() + JSON.stringify(myArray)` to `data: $(form).serialize() + "&arr=" + JSON.stringify(myArray)`. For Further help refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/10398820/4518930

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work even though the string was created. It happens that upon arriving at my Action, the array is null. Even though you have renamed *arr* to the name of the object that Action expects to receive :(

Comment: I was able to solve it differently as I posted my answer. Thank you for the tips :)

Answer (score 0):

`.serialize() + Some JSON String` doesn't make sense.

According to the docs:

https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded
>   notation.

So you're really taking a string like `foo=bar&goat=baz` and then adding a JSON string to like. Which makes no sense.

I think you'd be better off serializing the form yourself into a JSON object. Adding another key for your array and then dumping that object to JSON via `JSON.stringify` and that string is your request data.

Comment: I was able to solve it differently as I posted my answer. Thank you for the tips :)

Answer (score 0):

After the tip of Cody Caughlan, I created an object that adds all the properties of the form and the array itself. The code looks like this:

```
var dataForm = {};
$($(form).serializeArray()).each(function(index, obj){
    dataForm[obj.name] = obj.value;
});
dataForm["MyArray"] = myArray;
```

And ajax: `post: dataForm`.