# Showing the selected value of a dropdown list in the html code with jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I want to retreive the html code of a form in order to send it on submit.
For inputs and textarea, I can retreive the contents with:

```
$('input').attr('value', function() { return $(this).val();});
```

For select items , how I must process?
thank you,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: serialize() form and other parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398783/jquery-serialize-form-and-other-parameters)

Comment: You'll find it easier to just `.serialize()` the form, rather than worry about individual controls.  Although it's not clear what you mean by *"retrieve the html code of a form"* so you may want something very different `$("form").html()`

Comment: I want to get the code of the form in order to send it in an email, instead of printing the form

Comment: I will see the .serialize()